# What does this graph look like? $y = \log_x{2}$

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions

The equation is $y = \log_x{2}$, where **x is the variable and the base of the logarithm.** What does the graph look like?

In general, what does $y = \log_x{k}$ look like, where k is some real constant?

I cannot plug this into online graphers like fooplot.com because they don't seem to have a notation that allows putting x in the base of a logarithm.

Comment: Hint: $\log_x(2)= \frac{\log(2)}{\log(x)}$

Comment: @SquirtleSquad Thanks, this also answers my next question of what $\log_x{x}$ looks like. I thought it might be some strange curve related to $y = x^x$, but no, it's just a constant 1.

Comment: $\log_x(x)=\frac{\log(x)}{\log(x)}=1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this 
[Graphing calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator)..Type this log_x2 into it.
Here's the graph
[image]

Note the graph is basically..$$f(x)=\frac{\ln2}{\ln x}\approx\frac{0.69314718056}{\ln x}$$

and an asymptote at $x=1$.

Comment: @DrZ214 You're welcome :)

Comment: I see the asymptote, but I also see a strange wiggle in the left bottom curve. From bottom infinity, it curves towards the y-axis, but then near zero it curves back up along it. That is strange.

Comment: It doesn't exist at $x=0$..another interesting feature...You could try values nearer and nearer to zero and you will understand the behaviour..Note that $\log(x)$ is negative for $0<x<1$

Comment: Right but the curve has an inflection point. Functions like $x^2$ and $2^x$ don't have inflection points so I find it strange that this log has one.

Answer (score 2):

$$y(x)=\ln_x(2)=\frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(x)} \qquad \text{and more generally}\quad \ln_x(k)=\frac{\ln(k)}{\ln(x)} $$

[image]

Comment: Yep I see it now, but what is that strange behavior with the bottom left curve? It curves towards the y-axis but then turns in the opposite direction. Is it two asymptotes?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 cases. I changed your parameter from $x$ to $a$

[image: Graph Theory]

I hope this makes sense. If the base is from $0<a<1$ and the argument is variable it is Graph 1. If the base is from $1<a<infinity$ and the argument is variable it is Graph 2.